# How can I use a variable from one table as a SELECT parameter for another table in php

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a user who has registered themselves with an email address.
This is kept in a users table.
Now this user can book a class using a calendar booking system (where they have to manually enter the email address aagain) and this data is stored in a bookings table.
Now the question is, I would like to show all the bookings the specific user has made, Selecting by their email address (can

```
echo $userRow['email'];
```

which works fine and shows the right email address for the logged in user.
Now how can I select the bookings based on this email address? I have tried something like this:

```
$relevantEmail = $userRow['email'];


 $get_booking = mysql_query("SELECT date, start
FROM bookings
JOIN users
ON bookings.email = '$relevantEmail' " );
   while($row = mysql_fetch_row($get_booking))
{
echo $row[0] . " " . $row[1] ;
        echo "\r\n";
    }
```

But this somehow outputs really weird result - takes out only 3 classes booked and assigns them to 3 users - each user getting each class

something of the likes of:

> joe - class 1
>
> prick - class 1
>
> josh - class 1
>
> joe - class 2
>
> prick - class 2
>
> josh - class 2
>
> joe - class 3
>
> prick - class 3
>
> josh - class 3

please help

Comment: You want `WHERE`. `JOIN ... ON` is for joining tables based on keys.

Comment: Do you need any data from `users` table?

Comment: If you store the email along with the bookings in that booking table, then you should reconsider that architecture. You create redundant data, that is not how relational database models are meant to be used. Just image what will happen if a user changes his email address: you'd have to update _all_ entries. Instead the relation between a user entry in the user table and all his bookings should be done using a database internal user id.

Comment: @arkascha yes you are right, the only problem is I'm not that good with this yet and need to start with more simple forms and then try to make it more complex

Comment: Sure, all fine, I do understand that. But consider doing that step _now_ before you create facts hard to change again later. You are nearly there, since you already do a joined select which is exactly where you want to get to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using `Users` for anything, drop the join, and just use `WHERE`:

```
$get_booking = mysql_query("SELECT date, start
    FROM bookings
    WHERE bookings.email = '$relevantEmail' " );
```

Please note that mysql_* functions are removed in PHP7 and deprecated in previous versions. Switch to PDO or mysqli, and take advantage of prepared statements and parameter binding. This will prevent you from being open to SQL injection.

Comment: Even with WHERE it still does the same output and does not work as intended. not sure how to do the parameter binding properly, although I have attempted it did not end up well so I just tried to keep it simple

Comment: Check your table to make sure that the table hold what you think it does. It's interesting that it looks like you're getting 2 date fields, but you're echoing out the name and class ID. Are you sure that your echo is from this table and not from another query?

Comment: the output I've written there was just for illustration purposes - when I noticed it showed me 3 classes and each was shown 3 times, I thought it was dodgy and checked to which user their were assigned to. obviously now it outputs the dates and times 
2016-11-30 17:30:00 2016-11-21 17:30:00 2016-11-14 17:30:00

Answer (score 0):

---

@aynber somehow cannot seem to be able to tag you...
Yes changing the JOIN to WHERE did the job, only found out I had a little mismatch in the previous code and so it was not working as intended. 
works like a charm now,
Thanks a lot

Comment: You should be able to add this as a comment on the answer. But I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score -1):

Hi buddy no need to use the join query

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from bookings where email_id = (select email_id from login where email_id = '$relevantEmail')");
```